# Building a tkinter GUI module, so the main program doesn't need to import tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a GUI module that I can import in my main program without having to import tkinter there, letting just the module handle everything. Here's how I imagine that it might work:

> main.py

```py
import gui as g

def update():
    #Update the GUI with new Data from this main program

GUI = g.gui()
gui.after(1000, update)
gui.mainloop()
```

> gui.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

class viewer(tk.Frame):
    #Some variables
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize(400, 100)
    def initialize(self, width, height):
        #Initialize some widgets, place them on grid, etc
    def start(self):
        #Do some other stuff, make a main window, configurations, etc
        print('Started!')
```

Edit: "Don't ask for opinion"
How do I make this work?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import gui as g

root = tk.Tk()
GUI = g.gui(root)
GUI.after(1000, update)
GUI.mainloop()
```

The above is what I don't want.

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which are off topic here.

Comment: BTW: modules [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html), [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) and [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net) use `tkinter` and you don't have to import `tkinter` - so you can see how it works.

Comment: The above examples were fine, though too complicated for my level of understanding. I fixed it though via simple method inside the gui module which starts the gui and returns said object

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround that seemed plausible to me:

> main.py

```
import gui
GUI = gui.start()
GUI.after(1000, update)
GUI.mainloop()
```

> gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk
def start():
   root = tk.Tk()
   run = viewer(root) # <- The class provided above
   return run
```

Comment: you solution is short but for me it looks strange. To hide it I would put `root = Tk()` directly in `viewer.__init__`. The same with `root.mainloop()` and `root.update()` and then I could run it as `gui.viewer(update)`. Or maybe I would create `class Viewer(tk.Tk)`

Comment: It's that way because my code is longer than what I provided. For example I declare in the Viewer class 'self.parent = parent' and said _parent_ is provided as _root_. Then I have methods which hide the main window which require to address root and I found the best way to do this is by using 'self.parent'

Comment: the most important that your solution suits you :) Good luck.

Comment: Heh, thanks. I know it's not perfect, but when running on deadlines not everything has to be perfect as long as it works and not produces any bugs.